# Pydantic / FastAPI, how to set up a case-insensitive model with suggested values

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

Using FastAPI I have set up a POST endpoint that takes a command, I want this command to be case insensitive, while still having suggested values (i.e. within the SwaggerUI docs)

For this, I have set up an endpoint with a `Command` class as a schema for the POST body parameters:

```py
@router.post("/command", status_code=HTTPStatus.ACCEPTED)  # @router is a fully set up APIRouter()
async def control_battery(command: Command):
    result = do_work(command.action)
    return result
```

For `Command` I currently have 2 possible versions, which both do not have the full functionality I desire.

```py
from fastapi import HTTPException
from pydantic import BaseModel, field_validator
from typing import Literal

## VERSION 1
class Command(BaseModel):
    action: Literal["jump", "walk", "sleep"]


## VERSION 2
class Command(BaseModel):
    action: str

    @field_validator('action')
    @classmethod
    def validate_command(cls, v: str) -> str:
        """
        Checks if command is valid and converts it to lower.
        """
        if v.lower() not in {'jump', 'walk', 'sleep'}:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=422, detail="Action must be either 'jump', 'walk', or 'sleep'")
        return v.lower()
```

Version 1 is obviously not case sensitive, but has the correct 'suggested value' behaviour, as below.

[image]

Whereas Version 2 has the correct case sensitivity and allows for greater control over the validation, but no longer shares suggested values with users of the schema. e.g., in the image above "jump" would be replaced with "string".

How do I combine the functionality of both of these approaches?

Comment: have you tried version2 but with `action : Literal["jump", "walk", "sleep"] | str`? I feel like that should work but I haven't tried.

Comment: @julaine Just tested this, this indeed works, thank you! Also read up on it, looks like `|` in type hinting is [shorthand for Union](https://peps.python.org/pep-0604/), which also unsurprisingly gets the results I'm after. Feel free to add this comment as the answer so I can mark the question as answered.

Comment: I added it, though there are some other good answers.

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76131490/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71258131/17865804) helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the type as either a literal or some string and keep the validation:

```py
class Command(BaseModel):
    action: Literal["jump", "walk", "sleep"] | str

    @field_validator('action')
    @classmethod
    def validate_command(cls, v: str) -> str:
        """
        Checks if command is valid and converts it to lower.
        """
        if v.lower() not in {'jump', 'walk', 'sleep'}:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=422, detail="Action must be either 'jump', 'walk', or 'sleep'")
        return v.lower()
```

A purist might say that `Literal["jump", "walk", "sleep"] | str` is the same as `str`, but in this case both a human and a computer can infer that "jump" and the other two values are special inputs. It works for providing example values.

You may not want to repeat the literal values - a mypy-passing solution would be to make them an enum:

```py
from enum import Enum

class Action(Enum):
    jump = "jump"
    walk = "walk"
    sleep = "sleep"


class Command(BaseModel):
    action: Action | str

    @field_validator('action')
    @classmethod
    def validate_command(cls, v: str) -> str:
        """
        Checks if command is valid and converts it to lower.
        """
        if v.lower() not in Action.__members__:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=422, detail="Action must be either 'jump', 'walk', or 'sleep'")
        return v.lower()
```

Another solution would be to keep using the `Literal` instead of the enum and use [get_args](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_args) to extract the values of the literal type, as explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59171103/7465516)

Comment: If you decide to go this way, move the set of valid values out to a separate variable at least, to avoid having to declare what's valid values in two separate locations that mean the same thing; you end up having to update both the Literal and the set of valid values if you duplicate the allowed values in two locations

Comment: @MatsLindh good point. It isn't that easy to seperate out, since `Literal` only takes literal values and not a set-variable and , but I managed to find a solution using enums.

Comment: You can use `get_args` to check values against a `Literal` definition: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_args - for example: `valid_values = Literal["foo", "bar"]` and then `"foo" in get_args(valid_values)` is `True`, while `"baz" in get_args(valid_values)` is `False`.

Comment: @MatsLindh that is already at the bottom of my answer

Answer (score 4):

You can use a validator configured with `mode="before"` to adjust any values before validation (this was named `pre=True` in pydantic v1):

Example:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException
from http import HTTPStatus
from pydantic import BaseModel, field_validator
from typing import Literal


class Command(BaseModel):
    action: Literal["jump", "walk", "sleep"]

    @field_validator('action', mode='before')
    @classmethod
    def validate_command(cls, v: str) -> str:
        return v.lower()


app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/command", status_code=HTTPStatus.ACCEPTED)  # @router is a fully set up APIRouter()
async def control_battery(command: Command):
    return {"action": command.action}
```

Any case version of `jump`, `walk`, `sleep` will work, while other values will give a 422 unprocessable error:

```bash
$ curl -s http://.../command -X POST -d '{"action": "JUMP"}' --header "Content-Type: application/json"
{"action":"jump"}
$ curl -s http://.../command -X POST -d '{"action": "foo"}' --header "Content-Type: application/json"
{"detail":[{"type":"literal_error","loc":["body","action"],"msg":"Input should be 'jump', 'walk' or 'sleep'","input":"foo","ctx":{"expected":"'jump', 'walk' or 'sleep'"},"url":"https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.6/v/literal_error"}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [Case Insensitive Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76129550/how-to-make-case-insensitive-choices-using-pythons-enum-and-fastapi#76883868)

```
class CaseInsensitiveEnum(str, Enum):
    @classmethod
    def _missing_(cls, value: str):
        for member in cls:
            if member.lower() == value.lower():
                return member
        return None


class CommandEnum(CaseInsensitiveEnum):
    jump = "jump"
    walk = "resnet"
    sleep = "sleep"
```

[Documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/path-params/#create-an-enum-class)

```
@router.post("/command", status_code=HTTPStatus.ACCEPTED) 
async def control_battery(command: CommandEnum):
    result = do_work(command.action)
    return result
```

[image]

Comment: Enum values are not case-insensitive, are they? But an option is to implement the missing method yourself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76129550/how-to-make-case-insensitive-choices-using-pythons-enum-and-fastapi

Comment: Enum values are case sensitive for sure. 
But you get a nice response from FAST Api  
```{
    "detail": [
        {
            "type": "enum",
            "loc": [
                "query",
                "command"
            ],
            "msg": "Input should be 'jump', 'resnet' or 'sleep'",
            "input": "JUMP",
            "ctx": {
                "expected": "'jump', 'resnet' or 'sleep'"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Yes, but you also get that with the `Literal` syntax as OP asked about - since they already had that part worked out; the case sensitivity was the issue.

Comment: You are right! I will try to find if there is another way to achieve the desired behavior with Enums or else i will delete my answer as Off-topic. Thanks